# Is N prefix allowed in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am converting views from MSSQL to MySQL. I came across a statement like

```
SELECT     CODE, DESCRIPTION
FROM         PARAMETERMASTER
WHERE     (CODETYPE = N'CASTTYPE')
```

Does MySQL support N prefix? Is it necessary to keep "N" prefix in MySQL also?

Comment: Here it works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63bb5/2

Comment: How come you post the question here instead of trying? (It takes about 5 seconds to try...)

Comment: @jarlh The project has been done using MSSQL. Now i am trying to convert it. I should check from project interface to do proper validation(situation demands it). So, I posted here. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following articles have some good information on the question. The short answer is just that there's a type mismatch between the unicode column and non-unicode string literal you're using. From the KB article, it looks like omitting the N prefix might still work in some cases, but it would depend on the code page and collation settings of the database. That might explain the change in behavior, if you were previously having success with the no-prefix method.

http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-some-sql-strings-have-an-n-prefix.html

http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/239530/en-us

Comment: I have looked into these articles. I just want to know whether the 'N' prefix can be used in MySQL? Or will it lead to erroneous output while executing?

Answer (score 0):

There is no N prefix for MySQL literal strings.  There is something similar, but I have never seen it used.  Simply quote whatever text you want.

Comment: Does using N prefix give erroneous output?

Comment: Hmmm... I guess it works (probably to help with compatibility.)